# Inconsistent CAPTCHA Behaviour Between Mobile/Desktop

Tags: support, captcha

I most often browse the site from my phone. If I answer a question on the mobile site using my phone I **never** get a CAPTCHA. However if I do so on my desktop (Chrome) than I **always** get one.

What triggers this?

Comment: Note: I didn't get one when I posted this.

Comment: Always?  Hmm, strange.

Comment: @MatthewRead Actually, I tried using the site my PC the whole day and only got one on the first post. Yesterday 2 out of 3 times but 2 were in the 5 minute period. Is it somehow linked to activity on a given machine? I can't think of anything else as I logged in on machine several months ago.

Comment: FYI: I got them using my Nexus S with the *full site* view enabled. But not consistently, last occurrence is 2 weeks ago or so.